# JOIN table when selecting a max value of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below table structure that is successfully getting the max column value of a table for each `CommentID`. But I want to JOIN the table `tbComment` with `tbCommentBreadcrumb` where `CommentID` is the key.

**tbComment**

```
CommentID     IsLocked
1             0      
2             0
3             1
4             0
5             1
```

**tbCommentBreadcrumb**

```
CommentStatusID  CommentID   StatusTypeID
105              1           1                
106              1           4                
107              2           1                
108              3           1               
109              3           4
110              4           1 
112              5           1
112              5           4
```

Here's what I have working:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
   SELECT
     *,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CommentID ORDER BY CreateDateTime desc) as rn
   FROM
     tbCommentBreadCrumb
   WHERE 
     CommentStatusTypeID = 4
     AND CreateDateTime <= {ts '2014-02-09 09:44:57'}
) t
WHERE
   t.rn = 1
ORDER BY 
   CommentStatusID DESC
```

This returns over a hundred records and I want to further refine the query by only getting the records where the above query is true but also that each of the `CommentID` in the table `tbComment` is locked. Basically not sure where to JOIN `tbComment` and put the `AND tbComment.CommentIsLocked = 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are quite close :-)

```
SELECT t.*
FROM
(
   SELECT
     *,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CommentID ORDER BY CreateDateTime desc) as rn
   FROM
     tbCommentBreadCrumb
     WHERE CommentStatusTypeID = 4
            AND    CreateDateTime <= {ts '2014-02-09 09:44:57'}
) t
JOIN tbComment c ON t.CommentID = c.CommentID
WHERE
   t.rn = 1
AND c.CommentIsLocked = 1
ORDER BY CommentStatusID DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
;With CTE
AS
(
   SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CommentID ORDER BY CreateDateTime desc) as rn
   FROM  tbCommentBreadCrumb
   WHERE CommentStatusTypeID = 4
   AND   CreateDateTime <= {ts '2014-02-09 09:44:57'}
) 
SELECT * 
FROM CTE C INNER JOIN tbComment TC
ON C.CommentID = TC.CommentID   
WHERE  C.rn = 1
ORDER BY C.CommentStatusID DESC
```